# Elasticsearch is Aggregating by "Partial Term" instead of "Entire Term"

Tags: database, elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm currently trying to do something fancy in elasticsearch...and it ALMOST works.

**Use case:** I have to limit the number of results per a certain field to (x) results.

**Example:** In a result set of restaurants I only want to return two locations per restaurant name. If I search *Mexican Food*, then I should get (x) Taco Bell hits, (x) Del Taco Hits and (x) El Torito Hits.

**The Problem:** My aggregation is currently only matching partials of the term.

**For Instance:** If I try to match `company_name`, it will create one bucket for *taco* and another bucket for *bell*, so Taco Bell might show up in 2 buckets, resulting in `(x) * 2` results for that company.

I find it hard to believe that this is the desired behavior. Is there a way to aggregate by the entire search term?

Here's my current aggregation JSON:

```
"aggs": {
    "by_company": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_hit": {
          "top_hits": {"size":1, "from": 0}
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Your help, as always, is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If your "company_name" is just a regular string with the standard analyzer, OR your whatever analyzer you are using for "company_name" is splitting the name then this is your answer. ES stores "terms", not words, or entire text unless you are telling it to.

Assuming your current analyzer for that field does just what I described above, then you need another - let's call it "raw" - field that should mirror your `company_name` field but it should store the company name as is.

This is what I mean:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        ...,
        "company_name": {
          "type": "multi_field",
          "fields": {
            "company_name": {
              "type": "string" #and whatever you currently have in your mapping for `company_name`
            },
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in your query, you'll do it like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "by_company": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company_name.raw"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_hit": {
          "top_hits": {"size":1, "from": 0}
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't even tested this, but based on what I already know about ES, I'm sure this is the solution. You definitely helped enlighten me to a huge aspect of how ES works, that I should have already known, but didn't.